# Redmine plugin that replaces words via regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm very new to Redmine/Ruby trying to achieve a simple plugin that takes the current wiki page content and matches/replaces everytime a word occurs via regular expression. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word replacement can de done by using [`gsub()`](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/10/ruby-regular-expression-replace.html) with `\b` to match a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
irb(main):001:0> 'foo bar baz foo bar'.gsub /\bfoo\b/, 'replaced'
=> "replaced bar baz replaced bar"
```

Here is a more complete solution with a dictionary of words to replace:

```
repl = {'foo'=>'apple', 'baz'=>'banana'}
s = 'foo bar baz foo bar'
for from, to in repl:
     s = s.gsub /\b#{from}\b/, to
end
```

Result: `apple bar banana apple bar`

Comment: Nice marcog, thanks for that! However, the regexp part is easy, how can I hook this as a Redmine plugin to replace all occurrences in the wiki content? Thanks!

Comment: @FLX Unfortunately I've never used readmine nor have I written any plugins for it. Does it expose raw page content and let you modify pages easily?